# How to prove the lower bound of $\frac{x^2}{\sin^2x}$?

Tags: calculus

How to prove $$1+\frac{x^2}{3}\leq \frac{x^2}{\sin^2x}, x\in (0,\pi/2)?$$

I do want to show it by intermediate value theorem as
$$\frac{1}{\sin^2x}-\frac{1}{x^2}
=\frac{2}{\xi^3}(x-\sin x)>\frac{2(x-\sin x)}{x^3}.$$

However, this may corrupt, since the rhs $<=\frac{1}{3}$.

Comment: Im not sure on what set we are looking for the lower bound. For instance there is singularity at $x=\pi$ So it blows up. Basically the function is $x^2 \csc^2x$

Comment: @BigM This inequality is valid for small $x$...

Comment: @BigM: $+\infty \geq 1 + \pi^2/3$, so that's not actually a problem.

Comment: @Hurkyl I want to show that this inequality is valid for all $x\in (0,\pi/2)$...

Comment: Yeah.was thinking about something else

Comment: One of the common tricks to show $f(x) \leq g(x)$ identically on $[a,b]$ is to show $f(a) \leq g(a)$ and $g'(x) - f'(x) \geq 0$ for all $x \in [a,b]$. If this works for this problem, you'll want to continuously extend the r.h.s. to be defined at $x=0$.

Comment: @Hurkyl It would not be easy to obtain the inequality as you said...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might prefer to prove
$$ 1+\frac{x^2}{3} \le e^{x^2/3} \le \left(\frac{x}{\sin x}\right)^2 $$
For the second inequality, the slickest proof is perhaps
$$ \frac{\sin x}{x} = \prod_{n=1}^\infty \left(1-\frac{x^2}{\pi^2 n^2}\right)
\le \prod_{n=1}^\infty \exp\left(-\frac{x^2}{\pi^2 n^2}\right)
= \exp\left(-\frac{x^2}{\pi^2} \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac1{n^2}\right)
= e^{-x^2/6}
$$
but this requires a couple big guns in the [first](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sinc_function) and [last](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basel_problem) steps.  A more elementary, but tedious, proof can be had by comparing power series:
$$ \frac{\sin x}{x} \le 1 - \frac{x^2}{6} + \frac{x^4}{120}
\le 1 - \frac{x^2}{6} + \frac{x^4}{72} - \frac{x^6}{1296}
\le e^{-x^2/6} $$
The first and last inequalities here come from the usual bounds for alternating series when the omitted terms decrease in absolute value (which they do here if $x$ is not very big); the middle inequality is routine algebra, and is valid for $|x|\le\frac6{\sqrt5}$, which covers the interval you want.

[image: graph illustrating inequalities in elementary proof, from Wolfram Alpha]

Answer (score 2):

Your inequality is equivalet to $$1\leq\frac{x^{2}}{\sin\left(x\right)^{2}}\left(\frac{3-\sin\left(x\right)^{2}}{3}\right):=f\left(x\right),\, x\in\left(0,\frac{\pi}{2}\right).$$
 Now you can observe that $$\underset{x\rightarrow0}{\lim}f\left(x\right)=1$$
 and if you derive $$f\left(x\right)'=\frac{2x\left(2\sin\left(x\right)+\cos\left(x\right)^{2}\sin\left(x\right)-3x\cos\left(x\right)\right)}{3\sin\left(x\right)^{3}}$$
 you can find that, if $x\in\left(0,\pi\right),$ $$f\left(x\right)'>0$$
 so $f\left(x\right)$ is monotonically increasing in $\left(0,\frac{\pi}{2}\right)$, and this implies your inequality.

Comment: You've typed $\sin (x)^2$ instead of $\sin^2x$

Comment: It's the same thing. I use $\sin\left(x\right)^{2}$ if the sine is squared, $\sin\left(x^{2}\right)$ if $x$ is squared.